# Firebird RDBS on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, postgresql

Has anyone gotten Firebird3 to work on Ubuntu Server 18? I have been trying for 2 weeks. Would like to use Firebird as I have some experience with it. I'm about ready to give up and start with PostgreSQL. I started with Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. I thought the problems were because that. **So I switched to Ubuntu Server. Still nothing but problems.**

Sorry about not providing specifics. I have forgotten everything I have tried and all the errors. Mostly connection and security. And the problems do not always seem consistent.

Followed several step by step instructions. Never completely works. Including this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird3.0. The sample `employee.fdb` never gets built. The `empbuild` folder does not exist. There is a `employee.sql.gz` file I can extract but it is a SQL script to build the employee database. Some success creating a simple database with the CLI.

I can use the CLI but would like a GUI available. Tried with and without Linux Mate minimal as a GUI.

A few years ago I had no problems getting Firebird 2.5 and Flamerobin on Linux Mint 17.9. I build the database and imported data from a NexusDB database. And got the Lazaus IDE to connect. Firebird 2.5 has not been update for several years and neither has Flamerobin.